# Error:- you must write contentlength bytes to the request stream before calling begin getresponse

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to create Rest WebApi using .Net Core.

I have different WebMethods but stuck in [HttpPost] function as below:

```
[HttpPost] 

public string Post([FromBody] string s) 

{ 

s = “new”; 

return s; 

}
```

And trying to call from my client side using Button from Windows forms as:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 

{ 

string requestMethod =string.Formate(“api/Service”); 

string result; 

string s=”old”; 

//There is a class Rest_Client with constructor to assign values of localhost url, Method type(GET/PUT/Post), Content-type and PostData) 

Rest_Client client =new Rest_Client(localhost, PostRequest, s); 

result = client.MakeRequest(requestMethod); 

MessageBox.Show(result); 

}
```

Function in Rest_Client class:-

```
public string MakeRequest(string parameters) 

{ 

var request =(HttpWebREquest)WebRequest.Create(localhost+parameters); 

request.Method=Post; 

request.ContentLength =1; 

request.ContentType=”application/json”; 
//there are different function too for Get/PUT. for now i need only Post .

if(!string.IsNullorEmpty(PostData)&&Method==HttpVerb.POST) 

{ 

var bytes=Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PostData); 

reuest.ContentLength=bytes.Length; 

StreamWriter streamWriter =new StreameWriter(REquest.GetREquestStream()); 

streamWriter.Write(bytes); 

} 

var response =(HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()); 

var responseValue=string.Empty; 

var responseStream=response.GetResponseStream()) 

if(responseStream!=N=null) 

{ 

using(var reader =new StreamREader(responseStream)) 

{ 

ReponseValue=readerReadToEnd(); 

} 

} 

return responseValue; 

}
```

But I am getting the error *you must write contentlength bytes to the request stream before calling begin getresponse.*

I am new to C# and not sure what is wrong with the code.

Comment: In HTTP, the content-length header comes *before* the data, so yes: you are expected to tell it how much data there will be before you start writing (unless you are using chunked encoding) - otherwise it needs to buffer everything in memory, which is sub-optimal; where is the data coming from here? can you know the length?

Comment: as i mentioned in the post:  there is exposed function called Post in my server side returning the string and when i call it from the client i am passing the value of the parameter in the PostData parameter.